# How to use for identify the first and last instance of an event in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

```
> trial
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  Company `Jan-17` `Feb-17` `Mar-17` `Apr-17` `May-17` `Jun-17` `Jul-17` `Aug-17` `Sep-17`
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A            83.       0.      33.      52.       0.      91.      61.       0.      40.
2 B             0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
3 C             5.      69.       0.      63.       6.      58.       0.       0.       0.
4 D            48.       0.       0.       0.       0.      74.      93.       3.      18.
5 E            39.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
6 F             0.      90.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.
# ... with 3 more variables: `Oct-17` <dbl>, `Nov-17` <dbl>, `Dec-17` <dbl>
```

I want to calculate the first Month where the value is >0 and the last month where the value is >0

For example for Company A, I need the answers as Jan-17 and Sep-17

I have 1000s of such rows and would need a way to calculate the above said results.

How can I use the for loop and get the results?

Or is there a better way to identify the results

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col` from `base R` to get the column index for each rows where the value is greater than 0, then with `rowSums` get those rows that have only 0s, convert that to NA (`NA^`) and get the column names with `names` by passing the index

```
i1 <- max.col(trial[-1] >0, 'first')
i2 <- max.col(trial[-1] > 0, 'last')
i3 <- NA^!rowSums(trial[-1] > 0)

names(trial)[-1][i1 *i3]
#[1] "Jan-17" NA       "Jan-17" "Jan-17" "Jan-17" "Feb-17"

names(trial)[-1][i2 * i3]
#[1] "Sep-17" NA       "Jun-17" "Sep-17" "Jan-17" "Feb-17"
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can `gather` into a 'long' format and then `summarise` to get the `first` and `last` column names that satisfies the condition

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(trial, month, val, -Company) %>%
   group_by(Company) %>%
  summarise(First = first(month[val > 0]), Last = last(month[val>0]))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Company First  Last  
#  <chr>   <chr>  <chr> 
#1 A       Jan-17 Sep-17   
#2 B       <NA>   <NA>  
#3 C       Jan-17 Jun-17
#4 D       Jan-17 Sep-17
#5 E       Jan-17 Jan-17
#6 F       Feb-17 Feb-17
```

Comment: @AnirudhMurali  When there are all 0's what do you want to return?

Comment: I want to return NA

Comment: @AnirudhMurali  Updated the post

Comment: What does i3 do?

Comment: @AnirudhMurali  The `rowSums(trial[-1] > 0)` gets you the number of elements in rows that are greater than 0.  If there are no elements, it will be 0.  By negating `!`, the 0s are converted to TRUE and others into FALSE.  Then with `NA^`, the TRUE gets replaced by NA and others by 1.